# HTML email, body inside rectangle, remove indentation

Tags: html, outlook

I am generating some html-formatted emails and I want the email body to be inside a thin, grey rectangle, like this:
[image]

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<table style="border:none; width:840pt; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="background:rgb(231, 230, 230);height:10pt"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:10pt; background:rgb(231, 230, 230);"></td>
            <td style="width:820pt;">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:800pt; text-align: left;"> 
                                <p class="p1">Title goes here...</p> 
                                <p class="p2">Subtitle goes here...</p>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <p><img class="img1" src="C:\...." alt="image goes here" style="margin: 0px; align: right"></p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 10pt;background: rgb(231, 230, 230);"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:10pt; background:rgb(231, 230, 230);"></td>
            <td>
                <p>email body goes here...<br><br></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:10pt; background:rgb(231, 230, 230);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="background:rgb(231, 230, 230);height:10pt;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is, the rectangle causes *indentation* visible in the preview pane in Outlook:

[image]

Any ideas how this can be prevented so that it looks like in the previous message?

Comment: Have you considered actually using the HTML `<title>` tag?

Comment: Isn't <title> text only, so i won't be able to format it? The above code is just a sample to demonstrate the issue, in the actual email I am using the <title> element, but it's not printed in the email. I think it only works with browsers. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Are you using nested tables just to create the border? I know consistent support for HTML in email is horrendous but I thought border was one of the properties that worked?

Comment: Yes, I was nesting a table inside another to create a border - but turns out I was over-complicating this - <border> works perfect and achieves exactly the same without the annoying indentation. Thank you so much for putting me on the right track!